Plotting ImageOverlay on Folium maps fails
I'm making a project. I need to open a local GeoTIFF file and load it into the Folium map with PyQt5. For now, instead of GeoTIFF, I took a numpy array. If it is 500,500,3 shape, everything is fine.
import sys
import numpy as np
import io
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDesktopWidget
import folium    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    bounds_fin = [[30, 35], [35, 45]]
    center_lat = bounds_fin[0][0] + ((bounds_fin[1][0] - bounds_fin[0][0]) / 2)
    center_lon = bounds_fin[0][1] + ((bounds_fin[1][1] - bounds_fin[0][1]) / 2)
    
    m = folium.Map(location=[center_lat, center_lon], zoom_start=6)
    
    arr = np.random.random((500,500,3))

    image_layer = folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(
                image=arr,
                name="I am a test array",
                bounds=bounds_fin,
                opacity=0.7,
                zindex=1
            )   
    image_layer.add_to(m)    
    folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
   
    data = io.BytesIO()
    m.save(data, close_file=False)
    w = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    w.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())    
    q = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

and result

If shape is 1000,1000,3
arr = np.random.random((500,500,3))
for some reason the image does not load (just a white background in my case, even the Folium map is not visible).

This is the case on both Linux and Windows.
What am I doing wrong? Сan Folium render large arrays, or is it impossible?

As a result, I came to this decision: since I need to open GeoTIFF in any case, I use the localtileserver library, which cuts GeoTIFF into tiles in real time.
Code below
from localtileserver import get_folium_tile_layer, TileClient

....

tile_client = TileClient(fileNameGeoTIFF)
foliumMap = folium.Map(
                location=tile_client.center(),
                tiles=None, zoom_start=10,max_zoom=15,min_zoom=1, 
                )
tile_layer = get_folium_tile_layer(tile_client, name='test',
                        control=True,
                        overlay=True)
foliumMap.add_child(tile_layer)

....


